# how to call fetch in a sub component in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I saw some tutorials online and majority of the examples are using

a class component e.g

```
export default class App extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        //set state here and data source 
      } 

      componentDidMount() {
        //get json data here
      }

     render() {
       return(
          blah blah blah
       )
     }

}
```

what if I want a sub component to have a functionality that calls fetch , how to do it ?

```
    //NewComponent.js
    //this is my sub component
    const NewComponent = () => {
        return(
          <FlatList />
          //I want a list of data here
        )
    }

   const getData = () => {
     //call fetch here
   }

   export default NewComponent
```

so in my second code snippet how to call the getData in order for me to display the data inside the NewComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Personally I would go for #3

1. You can make your sub component a class and use React's lifecycle method such as `componentDidMount`
2. You can move `getData` function to another javascript module. Then import and call it from parent component. Pass the result as props down into the sub component.
3. Use React's [Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Pay attention to the section [Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) also.

Hope that helps.